# 'react-native run-android' with USB tethering not installing app on device (note 4)

Tags: react-native

I am trying to test my app through USB tethering (this app is currently working on Xcode and iOS Emulator). I have enabled tethering on 'Developer Options on my phone'

About Device

Samsung Note 4

Android 6.0.1

This is what i tried.

I ran this command

```
adb devices
```

[image: adb devices]

```
react-native run-android
```

[image: run android]

But the app is not installing on my Phone. Am i missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this with USB tethering. It seems like you need to do a bit more wiring to set up the app on your device outside of sharing internet connection. If you are open to an easy alternative you can try using [Expo](https://expo.io/) with [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app). If you have a simple app, you can run your code on your actual device by scanning a QR code.

The quickest way I've found to do test this out is with [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/react_native).

Comment: With Expo, do i need to install the module into my app, Whats the command. I had a look, Its confusing me a bit. when i run npm start i dont see any qr code.

Comment: You need to make you app using the tool create-react-naitve-app. Then you will have a QR code provided in the terminal. But I posted the repl.it link because there's no installation required there. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html

Comment: If you use create-react-native-app you'll need to install the Expo app on your actual device so you can use that to scan the QR code. You'll see a QR code when you run npm start in the terminal.

Comment: i wud still prefer something a bit more local for debugging. Like i did with Android Studio, compared to using these hosted solutions

Comment: I debug on the actual simulators and emulators rather than an actual device. If you run `react-native run-android` you need to make sure you have an emulator running before running that command. In the emulator you can run `⌘M` and then select `Remote JS Debugging`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150543/discussion-between-africa-matjie-and-turnipdabeets).